# Wordpress - страница для клиента с админкой

Tags: wordpress

Специалисты, подскажите, позволяет ли Wordpress создать страницу для клиента с админкой, чтобы клиент мог изменять информацию у себя на странице, то есть создать свою собственную страницу и управлять ее содержимым из собственной админки? Спасибо за пинки в нужном направлении.

Answer (score 0):

Не ясно что такое "у себя на странице", но у ВП есть механизм ролей и возможностей. С его помощью и реализуются различные доступы.

См https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/

Comment: Не надо гадать, просто нажмите "Закрыть" вопрос и все)

Comment: @WPPunk всё бы вам закрывать... Это не тот случай, когда стоит это делать. Вопрос вполне конкретный - ВП позволяет управлять доступом? Ответ -Да. А куда/к чему - дело второе. ТС не спрашивает КАК это реализовать в данном конкретном [изначально непонятном] случае.